# Iterating to an object from firebase angular data model

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all type from the /type in my angualr firebase app.

I have written a provider function

```
getAllDetails() {
    let fn = firebase.database().ref('/type').on("value", function (snapshot) {

        console.log(snapshot.val());
        return snapshot.val();
    });
    return fn;

}
```

and on the main class i am trying to pull all data in the Array

```
type: Array<any> = [];


ngOnInit() {

  this.type.push(this.db.getAllDetails());

}
```

But it is not pulling any Data in the ngFor Tag in the html , in the console the objects are getting printed. Attached images.

```
  <ion-select>
     <ion-option *ngFor="let item of type ">{{item.type}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZbip.png)

[image]

Comment: what do you see when you put {{item}}

Comment: all blank is coming